# AND/OR for roles in Loopback's ACLS

Tags: node.js, access-control, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have an application where users can have several of different type of roles

**Static Roles:** each determines a different level of permissions, a user is mapped to one of these roles

- *adminUser*
- *powerUser*
- *baseUser*

**Dynamic Role:**

- *accountMember*: this role is assigned if the resource the user is trying to access belongs to the same account.

Now, let's say I have two endpoints:

- */addUsers* : in order to access this endpoint, a user needs to have the *adminUser* role as well as the *accountMember* role `adminUser && accountMember`
- */editUsers* : in order to access this endpoint, a user needs to have the *adminUser* or *powerUser* role, as well as the *accountMember* role. e.g. `(powerUser || adminUser) && accountMember`

Assuming the roles are applied properly, how would I implement the AND/OR logic using loopback's ACLS array?

Comment: Its a very valid scenario, please post it on google group, Developers are very active there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flow I came up with for `(powerUser || adminUser) && accountMember`

```
[DENY *$everyone* for all methods]

[ALLOW *accountMember* on */editUsers*]

[DENY *baseUser* on */editUsers*]
```

and for `adminUser && accountMember`

```
[DENY *$everyone* for all methods]

[ALLOW *accountMember* on */editUsers*]

[DENY *baseUser* on */editUsers*]

[DENY *powerUser* on */editUsers*]
```

I don't really like it though because I was to add another user Role, then I would have to edit a lot of ACLS. I would rather implicitly allow *adminUser* instead of having to deny all other user types.